# How to write prepared statement using activerecord-informix-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, prepared-statement, informix

Using [activerecord-informix-adapter](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rails-informix/) (1.1.1) with its [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-informix-adapter/1.1.1/frames) I am trying to create a prepared statement but get an error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid 

Informix::DatabaseError: Prepared statement is not a cursor specification:
```

My query looks like this:

```
@resource=Client.connection.execute("select * from sample where username=?;",'John')
```

Comment: Is there some reason you're jumping past the active record stack to talk directly to the Informix adapter for this query?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to use AR directly using the Informix DB adapter. I don't even know for sure if its supported as the adapter has not been updated in years. I have a work around however, a method inside a model class: `connection.select_all("select * from sample where username='#{firstname}'")`

Comment: There are a few forks of his work from github that work with the 3.0x version of rails.  At some point I plan to update the driver with the changes that will make it work with 3.2 but it involves a more extreme rewrite.